# How to Optimize Retrieve-and-Generate Model for Context-Relevant Responses in a GPT-3.5 Chatbot?

Tags: chatbot, information-retrieval, large-language-model, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I am developing an internal enterprise chatbot based on GPT-3.5. The current implementation utilizes a Retrieve-and-Generate (RAG) approach learned in a class, where the user's prompt is used for vector retrieval to provide "known information" to assist the model in generating answers. However, this approach is proving suboptimal in many scenarios because the model receives "known information" that can interfere with its responses, even when such information is unnecessary for the user's query.

For instance, when asked about the water resistance of a smartwatch, model GP335, the retrieval system supplies related known information (e.g., "GP335 has an IP68 water resistance rating"), leading to a direct and possibly redundant answer from the model.

The issue becomes more pronounced when the user switches topics, such as moving from discussing water resistance to asking about size, or simply exchanging greetings. The previously relevant information remains accessible to the model and affects the quality of the responses.

Here are some specific scenarios:

User asks: "How is the water resistance of the smartwatch GP335?"

Retrieved known information: "GP335 has an IP68 water resistance rating"

Model responds: "The GP335 has an IP68 water resistance rating."

User asks: "What about its size?"

Retrieved known information (wrongly associated with another product): "Tank AX900 is 12 meters long and 10 meters wide"

Model responds: "Its size is 12 meters long and 10 meters wide."

User asks: "Hello"

Retrieved known information: "The installation process for smartwatch GP335 is 1...2...3..."

Model responds: "Hello, it seems you have provided detailed information on the installation process of the smartwatch GP335..."

What are some best practices, techniques, or strategies that you can recommend to address these issues?

```
def get_response_from_llm(session, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"):
    # Retrieve the latest user prompt from the session.
    user_query = session[-1]['content']

    # Convert the user prompt into embeddings.
    embedded_user_query = get_embeddings([user_query])

    # Initialize the vector database client.
    vectorDB_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="mypath")
    # Access the specific collection in the vector database.
    collection = vectorDB_client.get_collection(name="mycollection")
    # Perform a query in the vector database to find relevant documents based on the embedded user query.
    search_results = collection.query(
        query_embeddings=embedded_user_query,
        n_results=2  # Retrieve the top 2 results
    )

    # Build the prompt using a template and the most relevant document found.
    prompt = build_prompt(
        prompt_template,  # A predefined template for the prompt
        info=search_results['documents'][0],  # The most relevant document
        query=user_query  # The original user query
    )

    # Print the constructed prompt to the console for debugging.
    print(prompt)

    # Update the last item in the session with the newly constructed prompt.
    session[-1] = {
        "role": "user",
        "content": str(prompt)
    }

    # Use the client to send the prompt to the language model and generate a response.
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=model,  # The language model to use
        messages=session,  # The updated session with the new prompt
        temperature=0.7,  # Control the randomness of the output (0.7 is somewhat creative).
    )
    # Return the content of the first choice from the response.
    return response.choices[0].message.content
```

I tried to change my prompt, but it works very well.